# Restoring hover state after click for custom CSS buttons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS button that has normal, pressed and hover states. Everything works fine except that when the click has happened, I need to somehow know whether the style should be set to normal or hover. That is, I need a way of knowing if the mouse cursor is still hovering the element. How would one achieve this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the user doing a `mousedown`, then moving the pointer off (and perhaps on again) the button, you could do something like this:

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/7zUaj/1/

```
var mouseIsDown = false; // Track/remember mouse up/down state for the button

    // Handle mouseenter and mouseleave
$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    if (mouseIsDown) 
        $(this).addClass('pressed'); // If mouse button was down, and user exited
                                     //   and reentered the button, add "pressed"
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover pressed');  // Remove both hover and pressed when
                                           //    the pointer leaves the button
})
  // Handle the mousedown, track that it is down, and add "pressed" class
.mousedown(function() {
    mouseIsDown = true;
    $(this).addClass('pressed');
})
 // Handle the mouseup, track that it is now up, and remove the "pressed" class
.mouseup(function() {
    mouseIsDown = false;
    $(this).removeClass('pressed');
});

 // If user does mousedown, leaves the button, and does mouseup,
 //     track that it is now up
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    mouseIsDown = false;
});​
```

The state of the mouse is tracked in a variable and set in the button's handlers for `mousedown` and `mouseup`. The `mouseup` is also tracked at the `document` level. This will help the `mouseenter` part of the `.hover()` to know if it should set the `pressed` class or not.

*(Note that because the mouseup is also tracked on the `document`, if there are any other elements on the page that stop the event from bubbling, the `mouseup` would not be detected by the `document`.)*

**EDIT:** Made it so the `document` only tracks `mouseup`, and the button tracks both.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `:visited` state in your CSS? As for Javascript, `OnMouseOver` or JQuery [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) or [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) (depending on what you want to do) will tell you when the hover is happening.